# how to modify a XPATH parser?

Tags: parsing, xpath

I want to modify a XPATH parser, but I don't know how to start with.
The soure code look like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a "shift reduce" (see the S and Rs) table for an LALR parser.  My guess is that it is produced by the GOLD parser which produces application-independent parse tables.

But you won't reasonably be able to modify this without the original grammmar, and the parser generator.

Why would you want to modify a perfectly working XPath parser anyway?  If it isn't perfect, why don't you just use a perfect one?

Answer (score 1):

**It is meaningless to try to modify a parser if the set of rules and the codes for the terminal symbols (and the lexer) aren't available**.

The provided code looks like the action table for a general, table driven LR parser. However you also need the GOTO table.

**This whole approach is as unsound as reverse engineering**. If you want, just build your own parser starting from clean zero so that you'll have freedom and flexibility.